# How to bind Repeating Section from One List depending on DropdownList Selected Value in InfoPath?

Tags: infopath, infopath2010, infopath-forms-services

Hello I am new to Infopath!
I have Two Share point Lists:

```
 1. ClientList(ClientID,ClientName,Title,ID)
 2. ClientDocuments(DocumentID,RelatedClient,DocumentName,Title,ID etc)



"RelatedClient" field is **LookUp** Value which refers "Title" Field from **ClientLis**t.
```

I have populated ClientList using Client DataSource Connection which displays ClientNames and have Inserted Repeated section(data section) from ClientDocuments Data Connection.

On selection of DropDownList which contains ClientNames the Repeating Section must display Documents Related to that Specific Client.

Help Appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you can add conditional formatting to the repeating section:

> Condition: **RelatedClient** is not equal to ***dropdown field***
>
> Formatting: Hide this control